# Bamboo maven plugin cannot be found

Tags: bamboo

Last week one of our Bamboo build plans mysteriously stopped working with the error:

```
Could not execute task 'Maven Build of XXX' 
no Plugin with key 
'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.maven:task.builder.mvn3'
is installed.
```

This plan had been working successfully for months.  The plugin is installed and is enabled.

The system plugin is called "Atlassian Bamboo Maven Tasks Plugin" key="com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.maven" version 4.3.3 and it is enabled.
The module "task.builder.mvn3" is enabled.

We have tried disabling and re-enabling the plugin.  We have tried restarting Bamboo.  We have tried creating a new plan that depends on Maven3 and it also fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bamboo agent machine, or one of the services on it, was not finding the correct JDK.  We were able to fix the problem by pre-pending the JDK path to the PATH environment variable.